# How to get the text from a parent element only and not from its children - Protractor

Tags: angular, protractor

I wrote e2e tests using Protractor (within an Angular app) for a menu and tried to select a link element with the identifier as `by.cssContainingText`.

The HTML code looks similar to this:

```
<a class="parent" href="#">
  <svg>
    ...
    <title>Home</title>
    ...
  </svg>
  Home
</a>
```

But if using the `by.cssContainingText` Protractor selector in this situation, my test fails from time to time.

What is a good approach to this?

Comment: Going by writing unique css selector for the `anchor`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In selenium if you perform get text on parent element by default it will take all the child element text too, So when you perform `by.cssContainingText` it fails if you have child elements.

To avoid this 
**#1** - Instead of `by.cssContainingText` use xpath with function `text()='Your text'` 

**#2-** :-  Pass all the nested texts to selector (which is not good as locator is independent on other element)

So for above html code if you want to select `Home` then identifier would be 
`.//a[//title[text()='Home']]` or `.//title[text()='Home']/parent::a`